# Cannot find type 'AuthDataResultCallBack' in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

```
func logInUser(withEmail email: String, password: String, completion: AuthDataResultCallBack?) {     Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: completion)    }
```

But I keep getting an error saying: Cannot find type 'AuthDataResultCallBack' in scope

I have firebase imported but not sure where to look now.

Comment: Have you tried creating an interface/protocol with the `AuthDataResultCallBack` name?

Comment: Must of typed something wrong because I erased it and retyped it and all seems good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**typealias AuthDataResultCallback = (AuthDataResult?, Error?) -> Void**

If you see the definition of AuthDataResultCallback, it is an typealias.
So, instead of Using "AuthDataResultCallback", use closure syntax instead.

It is also mentioned in FIRAuth.h file , in FirebaseAuth module.
"Use Swift's closure syntax instead."